# Serialising C# object and preserving property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to post a serialised object to a web service. The service requires the property names 'context' and 'type' to be formatted as '@context' and '@type' other wise it won't accept the request.

Newtonsoft JSON.NET is removing the '@' from the property names 'context' and 'type' and i need them to carry through into the JSON. Can anyone assist?

Here is the class I am using

```
public class PotentialAction
{
    public string @context { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> target { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Here is the JSON that it is being converted to:

```
{
  "potentialAction": [
   {
      "context": "http://schema.org",
      "type": "ViewAction",
      "name": "View in Portal",
      "target": [
        "http://www.example.net"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But this is what I need it to serialise to:

```
{
  "potentialAction": [
   {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ViewAction",
      "name": "View in Portal",
      "target": [
        "http://www.example.net"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note that the `@` in the C# code is not actually considered to be part of the identifier, so the names of those property is *actually* `context` and `type`. The @ is used to tell the compiler that any syntax rules that would make the following word a *keyword* should be ignored and consider it as an identifier, but the `@` isn't added to the identifier. In other words, it isn't Json.Net that is removing the `@`, it is the C# compiler that isn't adding them because they mean something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, the [`@` prefix on a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) is used to allow you to use a reserved word, for example `@class`. So it will be effectively ignored. To control the property name for serialisation, you need to add the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute to your model:

```
public class PotentialAction
{
    [JsonProperty("@context")]
    public string @context { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public string @type { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> target { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some attributes you can use to define what the field name should be.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

You would be using it like so:

`[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@context")]
Public string context { get; set ; }`